# Can Tarjan's SCC algorithm find satisfying assignment to just 'any' digraph?

Tags: satisfiability

Is Tarjan's algorithm capable of finding satisfying assignment to any digraph consists of variables (vertices) and implications (edges)? I know that it solves implication graphs constructed by 2SAT clauses, but I wonder if the algorithm can handle the digraphs which cannot be expressed as 2SAT clauses. Let me clarify this by the following examples:

(a+b)(~b+c) translates to the following
(~a -> b),
(~b -> a),
(b -> c),
(~c -> ~b)
It is OK. But how about the following implications:
(a -> b),
(b -> ~c)
There is obviously no corresponding set of 2SAT instances. Does Tarjan's algorithm find a satisfying assignment to this?

Comment: The clauses $(a \to b), (b \to \lnot c)$ are [Horn Clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause#Definition).

Comment: They are, but they also might not be. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a faulty premise.  There *is* a 2SAT instance corresponding to $(a \implies b) \land (b \implies \neg c)$.  Just note that $x \implies y$ is equivalent to $\neg x \lor y$.  Then you can transform the original formula to $(\neg  a \lor b) \land (\neg b \lor \neg c)$, which is obviously a 2SAT instance.

That algorithm you refer to can solve 2SAT, but it can't solve anything stronger as is.  However, there *are* related graph-based algorithms to test satisfiability of arbitrary conjunctions of Horn clauses.

Comment: Your 2SAT instance has extra implications, $(\neg b \implies \neg a)$ and $(c \implies \neg b)$.

Comment: As Kyle Jones says, (~a+b)(~b+~c) has additional implications. I'm talking about the case where only half of the implications produced by 2SAT instances are given.

Comment: @KyleJones, no, those are not "extra" implications.  $(\neg b \implies \neg a)$ is implied by (in fact, equivalent to) $(a \implies b)$ -- it is the contrapositive.  Same for $(c \implies \neg b)$.  My 2SAT instance is exactly equivalent to the formula Husrev provided.  Try finding an assignment that makes my 2SAT instance true for Husrev's formula false, or vice versa -- I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Husrev, I suspect you might have misunderstood how boolean formula work.  See my comment to Kyle Jones.

Comment: Well, seems like I misinterpreted what I've figured out.  Maybe 'implication' is a wrong term for an edge of digraph: two skew-symmetric edges together gives an 'implication' or a '2SAT instance'. How about some digraph lacks the contrapositive edges? So it is not going to be an implication graph. Is it still solvable by Tarjan's thing?

Comment: @Husrev, I think your basic confusion is over what problem the algorithm solves.  Your question suggests you are thinking about this the wrong way.  The phrase "satisfying assignment of a digraph" has no meaning; that isn't defined.  Instead, we talk about the satisfying assignment of a *formula*.  The graph and the algorithm is only the means to an end.  So, you need to be clear in your mind about what *formula* you are testing the satisfiability of.  There is no way to have a boolean formula that includes $a \implies b$ without also implying the contrapositive.